# remotely executing a command using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, awk

Here I'm trying to remotely execute a command on multiple devices using ssh using while loop in `bash` however I'm getting output for the first IP in source file but not for others.

```
cat HPE_FRAMES_IP
10.123.112.184
10.224.20.120
10.18.133.53
10.18.133.28
10.18.133.14
172.18.171.91
10.1.180.99
10.1.180.70
10.1.180.77
10.1.180.95

cat HPE_FRAMES_IP | while read IP ; do ssh Reports@$IP showsys | awk '{print $2,$5}' ;  done

--Name--- Nodes
ABCHP8401 SL-NUMBER
```

Comment: @Weijun Zhou can you please help me with this

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference whether `awk` is executed remotely or locally I suppose?

Comment: 'cat HPE_FRAMES_IP | while read IP ; do ssh Reports@$IP "showsys | awk '{print $2,$5}'" ;  done'
_showsys: Invalid option: |_

Comment: Give ssh the `-n` option, otherwise it will gobble up all of its input and your while loop will run just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For loop seems to be good option here:

```
for i in $(cat HPE_FRAMES_IP); do ssh Reports@$i showsys | awk '{print $2,$5}' ;  done
```

Comment: 'for i in $(cat HPE_FRAMES_IP); do ssh Reports@$IP showsys | awk '{print $2,$5}' ;  done'
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known

Comment: `@$i`. Not `@$IP`.

Comment: already modified :)

Comment: I'm responding to the comment by user3016638.